# I want to find a manga/webtoon about a class on a field trip where this parasite that looks like blueish white eggs are everywhere

Tags: story-identification, manga

So a few years ago i found this manga/webtoon that kinda reminds me of *sweet home*. It's about a class going on a field trip when they discover a weird parasite that kinda looks like a small blueish white pile of eggs. But when it touches someone, it makes them feel like they're on fire, and it spreads then, making them want to spread it to others?

The surving classmates get on the zipline train that they took before and somehow manage to survive.

Some other scenes I can slightly remember are a whole bunch of survivors end up in a giant building where the main character discovers he's been infected but it doesn't take over him. Kinda like the main character from *sweet home*.

One of the classmates follow some police or miltary guys to find a girl he knows, but they think she's dead. She's not though.

It had like 40 to 70-ish chapters.

Comment: Since you mention sweet home specifically, was this anything else by Kim Carnby? He has a few other horror stories. Shotgun Boy in particular sounds like it involves parasites, but I didn't see any eggs. Did you read this story on Webtoons? Can you put a number to "a few years ago"?

Comment: im not sure really, but i didnt read it on webtoon. All i remember about the website was that it had a dark background.. There was another scene i remembered, it was where a few of the classmates got trapped in a building where another monster was in, but they found an escape route but going through one of the windows onto a ledge a little ways away. Some of them tried to leave behind the mc as 'bait', but one or two of them went back for him and managed to escape..

Comment: It had a similar vibe to sweet home but the art was definitely a different person's. Its mainly the mc gets infected but doesn't go all crazy, him and his schoolmates try and survive untill they can get help.. The parasite turns people into monsters, that sort of thing.. And i thnk in the first episode theres a dog that gets infected, or a couple with a dog..

Comment: "Infectee" has a dog eating a human and turning into a monster in the first chapter, but I didn't see any eggs. "Spore" is a potential match by tags, but I can't find any translations. Do the infected turn into monsters, or stay mostly humanoid? Or perhaps look/act like zombies?

Comment: No unfortunately thats not what im looking for, i do remember that they kinda humanoid and they act like zombiesish.. and the title was something longer, id remember the second a saw it.. the art too